# How to save a string in a list item? (C)

Tags: c

I can't copy this string to one array in a list and the program crashes when it reaches that line. Can you help to solve this? Thank you.

Here is the code.

```
typedef struct pedido pedido, *ppedido;

struct pedido{
    char id[5];
    int prioridade;
    int mesa, n_pratos;
    pprato prato[TAM];
    ppedido prox;
};

struct prato{
    char id[5];
};


ppedido AdicionaPratoMenu(ppedido lista, char ped[],char idprato[])
{
    int i,j=0,m=0;

    while(lista != NULL){
        if((strcmp(lista->id, ped)) == 0)
        {
            for(i=0;i<lista->n_pratos;i++)
            {
                m++;
            }

            strcpy(lista->prato[m]->id,idprato);   //This is where it goes wrong

        }
        lista=lista->prox;
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger! It will not only help you pinpoint the location of the crash, it will also let you examine variables to help you figure out the cause of the crash.

Comment: i use the dubugger, but i don't find the problem.

Comment: If you want our help, your code is not complete. For instance, the definition for `pprato` is missing. Don't make us guess that is't probably just a pointer to `prato`. You should try to post a complete program that is as small as possible while still exposing the error.

Comment: @MrLister "typedef struct prato prato, *pprato;", is this you're talking about?

Comment: One problem I see is that you reuse names. You have `typedef struct pedido pedido` first and then the declaration of `typedef pedido`. Also you have both an array and a struct named `prato`. This may not confuse the compiler, but it certainly can confuse us!

Comment: @MarcodeBarbosa Yes, that typedef. You should edit that into your post!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you've neglected to include here a:

```
typedef struct prato pprato;
```

There are two potential problems:

1. What does `strlen(idprato)` equal? My guess is that it's 5 or greater.
     Use `strncpy(lista->prato[m]->id, idprato, 4);` instead.
2. `m` must be less than `TAM` when you do the `strcpy`. When you're incrementing `m` in your for loop you should also add `m < TAM`, or just use this loop:  `for (m = 0; m<lista->n_pratos; m++);`

General tip: always use `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`; and `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`. Even if `idprato` will always have a length of 4.

Answer (score 1):

This is a potential out of bounds access if `TAM == lista->n_pratos`:

```
strcpy(lista->prato[m]->id,idprato);
```

as the previous `for` loop will only end with `TAM == m` (array indexes in C start from 0). To correct, ensure `m < TAM` prior to calling `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check

1. In, `lista->prato[m]` 'm' is less than 'TAM' in `pprato prato[TAM];`
2. Length of `idprato` is less than 5 (which is what you defined).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming 'pprato' is a pointer to a 'struct prato'. If so, you have an array of pointers to 'struct prato' but no memory actually allocated for them and then you're trying to dereference them in your strcpy().